# WFS Service - doesn't show any layer on QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs

This service has 36 layers. I can connect to the service from QGIS but any layer show up when it is selected.

Could any one help me out?

Link for the WFS Service: 
http://local.pentago.com.br:8090/arcgis/services/IDAF/DADOS_INSTITUCIONAL/MapServer/WFSServer

Previous I did some tests in a web browser to get KML response with success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me:

I added the [getcababilities url](http://local.pentago.com.br:8090/arcgis/services/IDAF/DADOS_INSTITUCIONAL/MapServer/WFSServer?request=getcapabilities&version=1.1.0&service=wfs) to the WFS to the WFS connections box and hit connect. I see the layers and can add them to my map.

I don't understand Portuguese so I have no idea what `GEO_FISC_LOCALIZACO` is but is shows up on the coast of Brazil with no issues.

[image]

Comment: Please try to load the layer "IDAFGEO.GEO_AA" from WFS service.

Comment: Please try to load the layer "IDAFGEO.GEO_AA" from WFS service. This layer is too big (many polygons).
I did a copy and past of URL below on Google Chrome browser and got this error message: 
<ogc:ServiceExceptionReport xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.2.0">
<ogc:ServiceException>
Linestring or poly boundary is self-intersecting[IDAFGEO.GEO_AA]
</ogc:ServiceException>
</ogc:ServiceExceptionReport>

Comment: http://local.pentago.com.br:8090/arcgis/services/IDAF/DADOS_INSTITUCIONAL/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=IDAF_DADOS_INSTITUCIONAL:GEO_AA&SRSNAME=EPSG:4674

Comment: That error means that the service provider has a topology error in their data and their WFS server requires valid data and therefore it throws an error. All you can do is to contact the service provider and ask them to fix their data.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, I had a similar problem. The layers would show in OpenLayers, but not in QGIS. I solved it by adding those elements in the METADATA block at layer level:

```
METADATA
    "wfs_title"                 "My WFS Title"
    "wfs_onlineresource"        "http://serveur1.test.local:8079/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\mapfiles\aga.map&"
    "wfs_srs"                   "EPSG:3857 EPSG:3798 EPSG:4326"
    "wms_title"                 "My WMS TItle"
    "wms_onlineresource"        "http://serveur1.test.local:8079/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\mapfiles\aga.map&"
    "wms_srs"                   "EPSG:3857 EPSG:32198 EPSG:3798 EPSG:4326"
    "ows_enable_request"        "*"
    "wms_enable_request"        "*"
    "wfs_enable_request"        "*"
    "wms_encoding"              "utf8"
    "wfs_encoding"              "utf8"
    "wms_feature_info_mime_type"              "text/html"
    "ows_feature_info_mime_type"              "text/html"
END #METADATA
```

I am assuming that you are using MapServer.

Comment: Obviously 1) Wilson does nor administrate that server and 2) the URL makes me think that it is an ESRI server:  http://local.pentago.com.br:8090/arcgis/services

Comment: This is an ArcGIS service not a UMN MapServer service.